# How to get UISlider thumb position

Tags: objective-c, vlc

How to know UISlider thumb position?
When I press a button I want to add a flag on the current slider thumb position.
How can I acquire the current thumb position so I can add the flag?

This is my synchronization code:

```
 _positionSlider.value = _mediaplayer.position;
```

This is how the slider should look like:

[image: look like this image]

Comment: I improved formatting and clarity of the question and included the image of the slider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This,
First create UIImageView

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
```

and write this below code in viewDiload() Function

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.slider.frame.origin.x, self.slider.frame.origin.y-20, 20, 10)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigateImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and add this slider event function

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider{

    CGRect trackRect = [self.slider trackRectForBounds:self.slider.bounds];
    CGRect thumbRect = [self.slider thumbRectForBounds:self.slider.bounds
                                             trackRect:trackRect
                                                 value:self.slider.value];

    CGRect r = [imageView frame];
    r.origin.x = thumbRect.origin.x;
    [imageView setFrame:r];

    NSLog(@"%f",thumbRect.origin.x);
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift version:

```
@objc func sliderChanged() {
    let trackRect = slider.trackRect(forBounds: slider.bounds)
    let thumbRect = slider.thumbRect(forBounds: slider.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: slider.value)

    arrowLeadingConstraint.update(offset: thumbRect.midX)
}
```